# NoMethodError: undefined method 'customer_details' for nil:NilClass in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

My RSpec test failed but I couldn't figure out how I could fix that. Calling `.all` method on the Class pass but it fails with associations.

**Error Message**

```
  0) CustomerDetail #index when logged in should render customer details index page
     Failure/Error: @customer_details = current_shop.customer_details.load

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `customer_details' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/customer_details_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'embedded_app'

  def current_shop
    @current_shop ||= Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: cookies[:shopify_domain])
  end
end
```

**Here is the Controller**

```
class CustomerDetailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    # This failed the test below and complains that NoMethodError: undefined method 'customer_details' for nil:NilClass
    @customer_details = current_shop.customer_details.load

    #This pass the test below
    @customer_details = CustomerDetail.all.load
  end
end
```

**Models**

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ShopifyApp::SessionStorage

  has_many :customer_details

  def api_version
    ShopifyApp.configuration.api_version
  end
end

class CustomerDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

**RSpec**

```
context 'when logged in' do
  before do
    @shop = create(:shop)
    @user = create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  it 'should return a 200 response' do
    get customer_details_index_path
    expect(response).to have_http_status '200'
  end

  it 'should render customer details index page' do
     get customer_details_index_path
     expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current_shop` is `nil` in your controller. It's not enough that you set `shop` in your spec code. Instance variables from specs are not shared with a controller under test.

Ensure that the shop you're creating in

```
    @shop = create(:shop)
```

has field `shopify_domain` set to whatever value has `cookies[:shopify_domain]` in your test request.

Comment: Followup: actually set that cookie in the test.

Comment: But `current_shop` wasn't nil in the controller. The controller runs well. Are you referring to the chained method (customer_details) being `nil`?

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi: "current_shop wasn't nil / the controller runs well" - not in this test, it doesn't. It probably runs well in your development env. Because you have that cookie set there.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. Any resources you can point me to @SergioTulentsev?

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi: I'd start with googling "rspec controller spec set cookie" (or something like that)